# Compare date in sqlite stored as milliseconds

Tags: java, android, sqlite, jodatime

I have a table in SQLite having date column defined as  `Numeric` type

```
KEY_DRIVER_STAT_DAT + " NUBMERIC"
```

Now I'mm inserting data in `KEY_DRIVER_STAT_DAT` columns as

```
values.put(KEY_DRIVER_STAT_DAT, DateTime.now().getMillis());
```

How can I get the records from this table where `KEY_DRIVER_STAT_DAT` is between 
`Current date` ?

Comment: why don't you use sqlite timestamp or date function to achieve same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with dates by their milliseconds values is tricky. When you insert record with millisecond value as date you insert it with the value of current moment. You need to search all records which are in time period from start of date (time of 00:00) and to the end of date (time of 23:59). Take a look at this example:

```
/*Suppose your DateTime is Joda's DateTime class*/
import java.util.*;
import org.joda.time.*;

// Two functions to help retrive start and end of date
public static DateTime getStart(DateTime date) {
    return new DateTime(date.year().get(), date.monthOfYear().get(), date.dayOfMonth().get(), 0, 0);    
}
public static DateTime getEnd(DateTime date) {
    return new DateTime(date.year().get(), date.monthOfYear().get(), date.dayOfMonth().get(), 23, 59);  
}

// Code to make clause and parameters for select-statement

DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime start = getStart(now);
DateTime end = getEnd(now);
String yourClause = "KEY_DRIVER_STAT_DAT >= ? AND KEY_DRIVER_STAT_DAT <= ?";
String[] params = new String[] {String.valueOf(start.getMillis()), String.valueOf(end.getMillis())}; 
System.out.println("clause: " + yourClause);
System.out.println("parameters: " + Arrays.toString(params));
```